# AWS Athena data input location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

According to the docs, when you create a table in Athena, you need to specify the location of the input data file in the s3 bucket. You can only specify the s3 location containing that file, but not the file to be used. For example I have many files like type1.log.gz, type2.log.gz, type3.log.gz of different format at a location my-bucket/logs/.

Currently the location given is 's3://my-bucket/logs/'

So is it possible to specify which file(say type2.log.gz) to be used.
Or do I have to copy the file(type2.log.gz) to another location having no other files and specify its path?

Answer (score 3):

Athena expects all of the data within an S3 location to have the same schema. This is a big help when you have a very large table, as it can be broken into many files that Athena can read in parallel, or when you want to add data to an existing table. However, that does mean that you simply can't use Athena in a situation where one S3 location has files with different schemas.

In your case, you would need to move the file you want to query to a different location, and then create a table pointing to its location--e.g. if you copy to `s3://my-bucket/logs/type2/type2.log.gz`, the table should point to `s3://my-bucket/logs/type2`.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. You are obliged to copy the file in an external bucket

Ref : [Confirmed by AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245192&tstart=75)